# Sending printStackTrace() to file via log4j without catching the exception

Tags: java, tomcat, exception, logging, log4j

I have a custom log file that is configured by log4j as follow:

```
<appender name="ARQUIVO" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="${catalina.base}/logs/docnix.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="Encodig" value="UTF-8" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
               value="[docnix] %d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
```

(more log configs)

However, since its a large application not always im able to catch a code that might throw a nullPointerException, and when that happens the stackTrace goes to tomcat's log file tomcat7-stderr ( for example ), is there a way to redirect ALL exceptions to my docnix.log? Without doing a lot of try/catch blocks to use the log4j logger?

I already messed around with swallowOutPut to try to redirect the stderr and stdout output to my file but, no luck so far.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure Tomcat to use log4j, see https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j

Comment: Ive tried that and seems that changes on my log4j.properties doesnt affect at all my logging files